# Is .inc an x86 suffix for a macro?

Tags: assembly, x86

I can't read x86 assembly so I try to learn to read it. Is .inc in the context of assembly a suffix for a macro? I look at code that seems to be x86 assembly (from a `.S` file where there seems to be no difference between the use of capital `.S` and lowercase `.s` (both uppercase `.s` and lowercase `.S` are main aasembly files).

```
#include <asm.inc>
#include <syscalls.inc>

.code

SyscallId = 0
#define SVC_(name, argcount) STUB_U name, argcount

#include <sysfuncs.h>

END
```

Comment: .S is a macro asssemly file for input to GASP .s is the output assembly file. .inc is a .S include and .i is the output translation unit of the C preprocessor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean `.inc` in `asm.inc`? That's a fairly common filename extension for files like this. There may be others like `.i` and `.mac`. I don't think a particular extension bears much importance. Most tools will probably gladly work with either.

Comment: I never compiled x86 assembly directly. Can the program `as` compile it? I did not compile the code, I just try to recognize what it is. Yes, it's more like code convention. I looked at MIPS and Nios assembly that use `.s` for a macro (like push and pop). `.i` and `.mac` are news to me.